# Sockets: getting UDP data into a word-aligned buffer using recvfrom without memcpy?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp

I admit to complete ignorance when it comes to programming sockets.

Actually I'm merely trying to write a very simple test harness for a bit of hardware with a working UDP interface on it. The test harness should be able to issue UDP packets to the hardware, and receive UDP packets from it, returning received UDP packets right back to the device with possible repetition.

The critical point is that the device expects data as 32-bit words. Which means the actual data content of the UDP packet needs to be word-aligned, and also on the receive side in my test harness I need to process the data buffer as a 32-bit word-aligned buffer.

Meanwhile, the size of the UDP header means that, coming out of the hardware, there's 2 bytes of padding at the front of the data field before the actual data, because when you add in all the various headers you end up with a start of data offset which isn't 32-bit word-aligned - it's off by a halfword.

What I thought would work is defining a word-aligned buffer in my UDP receive function, then passing to recvfrom a pointer cast to a char and then offset by 2 (corresponding to the halfword misalignment). In that situation the actual data words should come out aligned in the buffer returned to the user - the padding going into the second halfword of the first word of the buffer. But it segfaults in the recvfrom function. It's as if recvfrom is determined to place the start of the data buffer on a 32-bit word boundary, which is what it absolutely must not do.

Is that its internal behaviour, generally? If so it would seem that one is left literally with no option to do an absurd and inefficient memcpy; doesn't seem to me to be particularly credible that there aren't other solutions. So how can I get it to copy the data words correctly on word boundaries?

Here's the receive function. Note that if the active lines are replaced with the commented lines the function doesn't segfault, so I can definitely isolate these as the problem. (Doing this is just a debug step - it doesn't help with the problem because if that's done, then later when I go to read the words it doesn't work for the expected reasons)

```
bool EthernetSoftwareIF::receiveUDP(rx_entry_t &rxdata)
{        
        uint32_t *data_w = new uint32_t[350]; // need a word-aligned buffer
        //char *data = (char *)data_w; 
        char *data = ((char *)data_w)+sizeof(uint16_t); // adjust for 2-byte padding

    #ifdef SIMULATION
            // simulation mode
        int len = sizeof(this->remoteServAddr);
        int bytecount = this->socket_if.recvfrom(data, sizeof(data_w)-sizeof(uint16_t), MSG_DONTWAIT, (sockaddr*)&(this->remoteServAddr), &len );
                //int bytecount = this->socket_if.recvfrom(data, sizeof(data_w), MSG_DONTWAIT, (sockaddr*)&(this->remoteServAddr), &len );
    #else
        socklen_t len = sizeof(this->remoteServAddr);
        int bytecount = recvfrom(this->udp_socket, data, sizeof(data_w)-sizeof(uint16_t), MSG_DONTWAIT, (sockaddr*)&(this->remoteServAddr), &len );
                //int bytecount = recvfrom(this->udp_socket, data, sizeof(data_w), MSG_DONTWAIT, (sockaddr*)&(this->remoteServAddr), &len );
    #endif

    if (bytecount < 0)
    {
        #ifdef SIMULATION
            printf("EthernetSoftwareIF::receiveUDP: error during packet reception (error code: %d).\n",this->socket_if.lasterror());
        #else
            printf("EthernetSoftwareIF::receiveUDP: error during packet reception.\n");
        #endif

        return false;
    }

    rxdata.uiBytes = bytecount;
    rxdata.uiSourceIP = htonl(this->remoteServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    rxdata.uiSourcePort = htons(this->remoteServAddr.sin_port);
    rxdata.uiDestPort = REMOTE_SERVER_PORT;
        rxdata.pData = (void*)data_w;

    return true; 
 }
```

---

(in reply to immibis's answer)

yes, I know it's not giving me the headers nor do I need to see them. But the problem is that once you get *past* all the headers, the start of the buffer is not word-aligned. The size of the headers is such that the last data byte in the headers is at a halfword boundary rather than a word boundary.

So the data buffer will start at a halfword boundary. This means that the first halfword in the data buffer needs to be filled with padding, so that the *actual* data in the buffer is word-aligned. Then I need to read the words out of the buffer, beginning at the first real word. What I'll be seeing in the UDP packet I actually receive is:

```
<halfword_padding><first_word><word>...<last_word>
```

What I want to do, therefore, is ensure that the receive buffer that I set up recvfrom to write into is word-aligned at the start of its allocated space, but that the halfword padding that is the first part of the data that will come from the received udp packet is placed into the second halfword in that buffer, so that the subsequent actual first word of my data will be in the second word of the allocated receive buffer, and I can read straight out of it on word-aligned boundaries. So the data buffer, once filled, should look like:

```
<first_halfword(ignored)><halfword_padding><first_word><word>...<last_word>
```

Does this make sense?

---

Update 26 February 2014

I've been doing some experimentation with the recvfrom lines and how I set up buffers data_w and buffer pointer data. What seems to be clear is this:

If the buffer pointer you provide in the *buffer* argument of recvfrom points to the *start* of your allocated buffer, then recvfrom proceeds normally. However, if you give it a pointer with an offset from the start address of the allocated buffer, the result is **unpredictable**. Various different ways of specifying offsets and buffer lengths resulted in wildly different outcomes.

So in my situation, if I give recvfrom a pointer to data_w, (which I can cast to any type, it seems), then recvfrom succeeds. But if data is derived from a cast-to-type and offset, then recvfrom breaks in all sorts of different and superficially unrelated ways.

I don't understand how it can be possible that recvfrom could be sensitive to the offset into a buffer declared externally, but the facts I've seen are the facts. Maybe someone can shed some light on the internals of recvfrom that can account for this behaviour.

In the meanwhile, if this is truly the case, then it seems that the conclusion is: if you need to read data that was aligned on word boundaries within the total UDP packet - and thus had at least 2 bytes of padding at the beginning of the data portion of the packet - you have no choice but to use memcpy to realign the data. That seems a bit hard to believe - surely there are other options available that don't require heaving things between 2 different buffers?

Comment: I don't know why you're concerned about udp headers. Your application does not see them. The data read into your buffer is the payload, not the raw udp packet.

Comment: Also, `sizeof(data_w)` is nonsense. It's not your buffer size; it's the size of a pointer. So you're only reading 4 (or 8, on a 64-bit system) bytes of data.

Comment: There are several *non sequiturs* in this question. Whatever the device sends you is what you have to process, but as you won't be receiving UDP headers at all, or if you do you will be receiving them into a different place, your requirement is basically imaginary.

Comment: Do you know that memcpy is actually an issue? I've seen it get optimized out before now, the compiler just keeps track of the copy and used the original data instead without actually copying it. Obviously that depends very much on how you use the data...

Comment: It's more accurate to say that memcpy isn't an issue (i.e. something that causes non-functionality) but rather something that *fixes* an issue (recvfrom copying the data out of word alignment), but at the price of an inefficiency. As far as I can see the memcpy must be moving all the data words into a new buffer, this one aligned on word boundaries. What's surprising is that the original recvfrom doesn't seem to be able to accept buffers with offsets, so that you can ensure word alignment *ab initio*

Answer (score 1):

`recvfrom` does not give you the headers. It only copies the data from the packet into your buffer. If your buffer is word-aligned, then the start of the data will be word-aligned.

You shouldn't need to care at all about UDP (or IP, or Ethernet) headers when using sockets.

Comment: Hi, yes, I know it's not giving me the headers nor do I need to see them. But the problem is that once you get *past* all the headers, the start of the buffer is not word-aligned. The size of the headers is such that the last data byte in the headers is at a halfword boundary rather than a word boundary. So the data buffer will start at a halfword boundary.

Comment: Sorry, you have a garbled comment above because it seems the comment system doesn't allow carriage returns; it interprets them as submitting the comment, and then my attempts to edit the comment ran out of time (apparently you only have 5 minutes to edit a comment). Anyway, see the full response below, written as an "answer" because I ran out of space in the comment field.

Comment: @user3228740 This makes no sense. The first byte of the UDP payload gets copied into the first byte of the pointer you pass to recvfrom(), and so on. Now, if your device/operating system have some very specific requirements - e.g. it _needs_ the pointer passed into recvfrom() to be 4 byte aligned, or similar, you need to verify those requirements, and tell tme to us. The other thing you might require is that you are going to cast the received buffer into a struct or similar, and that struct needs a 4 byte alignment(or 2 byte alignment) -but that's not going crash in recvfrom(). Please clarify.

Comment: Exactly. The first byte of the payload will go into the first byte of the structure passed in recvfrom. But that means that the first 2 bytes will be the 2 pad bytes. So the "real" words, beginning at byte offset 2, will be off by a halfword from native word. alignment. I can't just create a buffer of chars, because then there's no easy way to guarantee that byte offset 2 of the byte buffer will be aligned on a word boundary. It's not the start address of the buffer pointer that needs to be aligned; it's the *real data*, beginning at byte offset 2.

Comment: @user3228740 Your answer was probably deleted for not being an actual answer. The first byte you send is the first byte you receive. There is no hidden padding. If you send the bytes {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} then you receive {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} in your receive buffer. You do not get {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} in your receive buffer.

Comment: You receive exactly what you send, or nothing at all, unless someone is tampering with your connection or there is bad packet corruption.

Comment: But that's exactly what I've been saying. My device *is* sending this padding, and I also need to send it back, when I send the data back to it. When I receive a data packet from the device, I *will* see the first 2 bytes in the receive buffer as 0, 0 (if I don't then my device is broken!) The device on the other side is ABSOLUTELY NOT using the sockets interface, nor can it (it's an embedded device with VERY limited instruction memory) In other words, if I got {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} in my receive buffer instead of {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} there would be something VERY wrong.

Comment: So the device is intentionally sending {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}? Okay, but you said that the padding comes from the UDP header. That might be the reason your device sends another two bytes, but it's nothing to do with sockets. IMO your question was badly worded.

Comment: It's clear that my reference to "the size of the UDP header" threw a lot of people. I'm sorry; I wasn't expecting that to be a source of confusion. What I meant by that is, when you add up the total sizes of the fields in a UDP frame header (14 for MAC, 20 for IP, 8 for UDP), you end up at 42: a non-word-aligned total. The data begins immediately but if you're building the frame in a device you have to put 2 pad bytes in the first 2 positions before beginning your actual data, if the actual data is to be word-aligned. when you go to read it with sockets, you have to account for those pad bytes

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the hardware generates a UDP payloaad of < pad>< pad>< 32 bit word>< 32 bit word>... Do I understand this correctly?

How about just doing something like :

```
union tp {
    uint32_t w;
    uint8_t b[4];
};

union tp rxbuffer[number of words + 1];
uint32_t *payload_ptr = &rxbuffer[1].w;
uint8_t * recvptr = &rxbuffer[0].b[2];
```

Or one of its type punny equivalents? 
Then you pass recvptr to recvfrom, and access the payload using payload_ptr which is 32 bit aligned because rxbuffer is.

The type punning is not totally safe per the standard, but is ok almost everywhere in practise (doing it via a union means it even works with gcc and -fstrict-aliasing).

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten the same problem yet, search anybody else has the same problem, found this entry. I have a simple solution, but firstly a little bit expanation:
UDP was created in the 80th of the foreign century, and the standards are and should be long time stable. Elsewhere many incompatibility problems may occur. But ... The developers in the 1980th have unfortunately not thought about 32 bit alignment in memory.

I have the problem, that the header and the payload is one after another in the same memory. I do not use a standard hardware Ethernet adapter, instead work on a special solution, Single Pair Ethernet on normal controllers with fast data exchange. See https://vishia.org/spe/index.html
Because of the alignment problematic I have all data of the header in one structure, for example for UDP:

```
typedef struct UdpHeader_Telg_Ethn_T {
  uint16 dstMacAddr[3];
  uint16 senderMacAddr[3];
  uint16 typeId;                     //: 0x0800 for UDP See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet#Das_Typ-Feld_(EtherType)[]
  //union UDPorIP_T {
    //struct UDP_T {
      uint16 version_lenHdr_Flags;    //: 0x4500 for UDP 5=5*4 Byte header
      uint16 lenIPdata;               //: @0x10 length incl. IP header, from version_lenHdr ... excl. FCS-CRC
      uint16 seq;                     //: currently number
      uint16 flg;
      uint16 TTL_Type;                //: Time to live 0x80 for 128 hops, and Type 0x01 for UDP
      uint16 chkIPdata;                     //: check code
      uint16 senderIp[2];             //: @0x1a first word MSW 192.168, then LSword, note: It is not aligned at a 32 bit position!
      uint16 dstIp[2];                //: @0x1e first word MSW 192.168, then LSword, note: It is not aligned at a 32 bit position!
      // end IP header
  uint16 senderPort;                  //: @22 src or sender port
  uint16 dstPort;
  uint16 lenUDPdata;
  uint16 checkUDPdata;
  /**After head, some udpData: Here only one word is defined, which also assures the 32-bit alignment. */
  uint16 udpData[1];                   //: One can use this array with free indexing to access the payload as universal uint16.
} UdpHeader_Telg_Ethn_s;
```

You see here on the out-commented stuff, the idea to structure the head has not work.

The last element is one uint16 as payload. As commented it can be used as payload by itself, taken the pointer to the array. But of course I have a complete specific struct for the payload. My simple solution is: This specific struct is recuced for the first 16 bit word, and the first 16 bit are written in this UDP header struct on udpData[0]. Usual a payload starts with common data, not with the specifics, so that is sensible.

Of course now I can get the problem, that my specific data are unaligned. For my task now I use a Texas Instruments TMS320, which aligns separates struct to 32 bit, but data elements in a struct also with 16 bit.
If I use memcpy, no problem occurs. You can usual copy data from your specific payload in the 16-bit-aligned datagram's payload. But I have really only one memory range for both.

That's why I have thought about a common solution: Define a user specific payload starting from the UDP's payload byte address 0x002, handle the first 16 bit always manually. So the mistake that UDP head is not 32-bit-aligned is resolved for this approach. Than, the modern UDP datagram of the 21th century has the first 2 bytes of UDP payload specific, and the rest is 32-bit alignable.

Resulting, on the receivers side (PC) I use the payload for data evaluation only from the positon 0x02. The position 0x00, 01 can be used for common information. Adequate in the revers direction.